# creating an angular package that has RouterModule as a dependancy

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to create a package using 
[Angular library starter](https://github.com/robisim74/angular-library-starter)

Everything works fine until I add RouterModule.

The module that causes an issue

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ClientMenuComponent } from './client-menu/client-menu.component';
import { ClientMenuItemComponent } from './client-menu-item/client-menu-item.component';
import { RouterModule, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([]) <---- Error: AoT compilation failed 
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClientMenuComponent,
    ClientMenuItemComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ClientMenuComponent,
    ClientMenuItemComponent
  ]
})
export class ClientMenuModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: ClientMenuModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
    static forChild(): ModuleWithProviders  {
        return {
            ngModule: ClientMenuModule,
            providers: []
        };
    }
}
```

This is the full error I get.

```
Error during template compile of 'ClientMenuModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'RouterModule' was called.

Error: AoT compilation failed
```

The environment that i'm using is

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.11.1
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull out the function call:

```
export const MyModule = RouterModule.forRoot([]);


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MyModule   
  ],
  declarations: [
    ClientMenuComponent,
    ClientMenuItemComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    ClientMenuComponent,
    ClientMenuItemComponent
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a library or a module that will be imported into other libraries/modules you SHOULD NOT call the `.forRoot()` function when you pass it into the `@NgModule`.

RouterModule declares and exports some directives, e.g. router-outlet, routerLink, routerLinkActive etc. Also, it provides some services e.g. Router, ActivatedRoute etc. To avoid having multiple instances of services, RouterModule defines two methods, "forRoot" and "forChild". As the name suggests, "forRoot" method should be called only by root module, i.e. app.module, and forChild should be called by other feature modules. This way, you still get to use directives, components, pipes exported by this module and don't get new instances of services.

While this doesn't specifically get the root of your issue, it will likely resolve your issue. (Also this [issue](https://github.com/dherges/ng-packagr/issues/778#issuecomment-382353997) may help)